# The post loop doesn't work

Tags: posts

I am beginner of wordpress.

```
                <?php if( have_posts() ): 
                    while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

                        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                        <p><?php the_category(); ?></p>
                        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

                 <?php
                    endwhile;
                endif;

                ?>
```

I use this post loop once, But now this doesn't work. Where am I doing mistake. I search but I can't understand very well. Thank you.

----------------------------- EDİT -----------------------------

I create topic like that.

[image]

And result is like this:  (just lile page title).

[image]

Also if you want my page.php code :

```
    <?php if(is_page(albumlerimiz)): ?>
    <div id="albumlerimiz">
        <div class="baslik">
            <h1> Albümlerimiz </h1>
        </div>  

        <div class="content">
         <div class="container">
           <div class="center-align">
              <div class="portfolio_filter">
                <ul>
                    <li data-filter="*"> TÜM ALBÜMLER </li>                    
                    <li data-filter=".dugun"> DÜGÜN ALBÜMLERİ </li>                    
                    <li data-filter=".cocuk"> ÇOCUK ALBÜMLERİ </li>                    
                    <li data-filter=".okul"> OKUL ALBÜMLERİ </li>                    
                    <li data-filter=".sunnet"> SÜNNET ALBÜMLERİ </li>                    
                </ul>        
              </div>


              <div class="portfolio_items">

                <?php if( have_posts() ): 
                    while( have_posts() ): the_post(); ?>

                        <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                        <p><?php the_category(); ?></p>
                        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

                 <?php
                    endwhile;
                endif;

                ?>

            </div>
        </div>

       </div>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: What's not working, can you give more info?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. The problem must be elsewhere

Comment: Okay. I describe more details, I edit post. Thanks for care.

Comment: `page.php` is used to display pages. Your are trying to display posts. What is in your `index.php`?

Comment: from what file is your posted code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to admin (Wordpress Portal) > Settings > Reading, look to "Front page displays" and make sure "Your latest posts" is checked

https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_Screen

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
 $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=>-1));
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
 <h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
 <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>   
<?php endwhile;
?>
```

this is the right answer.....

Answer (score 0):

As per my understandings of your issue:

You are not querying posts you need to show.
Use `wp_query()` to query your posts before loop.

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=>-1));
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    //your code here
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer go to setting -> reading -> make sure your latest posts checked as image below

[image]